# Who created a database in my SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I'm trying to determine **who** created a database in my SQL Server instance. The `.trc` logs seem to have been purged and I can't locate a backup of them. I know when the database was created and have found the `.bak` file that was used to create the database, but I can't determine **WHO** created it.

Any other ideas how I can figure this out? (SSMS schema history report also doesn't go back far enough)

Comment: select * from  sys.databases.. you can find .bak files location and all databases owner_sid and you can find by Right click SQL Server Instance and Select Reports -> Standard Reports -> Schema Changes History https://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/SQL-Server-Find-which-user-deleted-the-database-in-SQL-Server/

Comment: [The only place where this information is written is in the transaction log](https://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/303/SQL-Server-Who-created-the-database.aspx). If you don't have the backups then you can only get estimated guess.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following [article](https://sqlity.net/en/2180/default-owner/):

> There is no dbo concept for server scope securables. They are always owned by the login that created them, no matter of any server roles that the login might be a member of.

So by default, the database owner is the one who created the database, but you have to make sure that no one changed this property:

To check the database owner, in SQL Server management studio, Right click on the database and in the Properties window >> General Tab >> check the owner property:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this sql statement to check who created sqlsvr DB and when it was created.

```
SELECT dd.name as database_name, pp.name as Created_by, dd.create_date 
FROM sys.databases dd, sys.server_principals pp
WHERE pp.sid = dd.owner_sid;
```